# Shopware 6 Administration: Where come from the value of property id in new entity

Tags: vue.js, shopware6

Right after create the new entity `this.myEntityRepository.create()` a call `this.myEntity.id` returns the created id.

Where come from this id? In new entity does not exist such property:

```
{
    "extensions": {},
    "_isNew": true
}
```

I know, the id was created in `entity-factory.data.js`?

```
create(entityName, id, context) {
        id = id || utils.createId();
    ...
```

How works the access using `this.myEntity.id` to the property value?

Answer (score 0):

The reason should be in the [defined property enumerable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) in `Object.defineProperty` of `id`  in class `Entity.js`:

```
// ~/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/node_modules/@shopware-ag/admin-extension-sdk/es/data/_internals/Entity.js
class EntityClass {
    constructor(id, entityName, data, options = {}) {
        var _a, _b;
        Object.defineProperty(this, "id", {
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true,
            writable: true,
            value: void 0
        });
...
```

[this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rammi2211/zk79uc1h/) show the behavior